# Cycles or multiple cascade paths SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm using dotnet and mvc in this project.

In my data model there is a multiple cascade paths and as a result of that I'm getting the error in the title. It happens when I try to add a FK from the `Orders` table to the `Business` table.

My data model :

- User (UserId pk , ...)
- Business (BusinessId pk, owner fk to User(UserId),...)
- Provider (ProviderId fk to User(UserId),....)
- Order (OrderId pk, BusinessId fk to Business(BusinessId),
       ProviderId fk to Provider(ProviderId), 
       CustomerId fk to User(UserId)).

For example, let's assume I have a web platform that can manage multiple barber shops. Each barber shop is a business in my database. A user in my site can be a customer (User), a barbershop owner (Business owner), and a barber (Provider).

Now, as you can understand, there are multiple paths from the user table to the order table.

The FK from Order to Provider is set to on delete set to null. Still, because we have a FK to Business (which has an owner that connected to User) I'm still stuck.

Error:

> Failed executing DbCommand (16ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   CREATE TABLE [Order]
>   ....
>   );
>
> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Order_Business_BusinessId' on table 'Order' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Looking for a solution on the dotnet level like updating the models or the migration file.. I heard about triggers but not sure how to implement it through asp.

Optional : Idea that I thought about : devide the orders table to 3 tables : 
Orders(Orderid pk,timestamp)
CustomersOrder(Order_id fk, customer_Id)
BusinessOrder(Orderid fk,businessID,ProviderId)

I would be happy to hear ideas if you guys have any  :)

Comment: You say you're getting an error, but you don't tell us the SQL you're using to get said error, or what the error is. We can't help you if we don't know what you're doing or what the problem is.

Comment: I thought that it was clear but I'll add it also to the main post. I'm getting the error when I try to add fk from order to business.

Comment: It's not clear, no. Your sentence states *"I'm getting this error."* and then you never produce that error... Neither do you give the SQL that generates it.

Comment: I'm using mvcc and dotnet, therefore it is generated for me. Still, I mentioned in the post that it happens when it tries to add a fk.

Comment: @Larnu I hope that it is clear now

Comment: The problem is what the error is telling you *"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Order_Business_BusinessId' on table 'Order' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."* It can't really be more clear. You can't have a `CASCADE` delete like that in SQL Server.

Comment: I understand that very well, please read my post. I was asking if there is any idea how to solve this type of problem ? I'm pretty sure that this data model issue has some kind of solution in sqlserver

Comment: Is it `mvc` or `mvcc`?

Comment: It is mvc, it was a mistake, I updated it..

Answer (score -1):

I guess I didnt have any other option, I devided the Order`s model into 3 models : Orders,CustomerOrder,BusinessOrder  = 3 tables.

Comment: You can simply configure the FK to have no cascade action.  Then you manage the deletes in your application.

Comment: Yeah I guess this is also a good options but I wanted the db to manage it for me. Thank you very much for the suggestion !